# RDP has suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I have a VAIO, I recently did some standard updates and replaced McAfee with AVG free.  Since then Remote Desktop has not worked.  It attempts to connect then gets as far as "Securing Remote Connection" then freezes, this freeze also makes the laptop excusably slow so a restart is required.

I've uninstalled AVG, disabled firewalls with no success.

It makes no difference whether I connect via name or IP.

Telnet appears to connect fine.

How can I get Remote Desktop working again?

Comment: Trial and error has proved that changing the display from Highest to High soves the issue.  My Graphics card driver is up to date...

Comment: I'm unclear, are you connecting *to* the VAIO or are you using the VAIO to connect to another computer?

Comment: @StephenJennings I am using the VAIO to connect to the other computer.  I have tried a variety of other target machines.  I can connect if I turn down the display to High colour but ideally I'd like to avoid having to do this each time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial and error has proved that changing the display from Highest to High soves the issue. My Graphics card driver is up to date